# Casperjs Login will not work keep getting resubmission error

Tags: linux, authentication, casperjs

Here is my test.js file which I execute with command `sudo casperjs test test.js > 2.txt`:

```
casper.start('https://www.bt.com/wifi/secure/statuscheck.do', function() {
this.fill('form[name="LoginForm"]', {
   'username': 'LOGIN',
   'password': 'PASS'
}, true); 
});

casper.wait(2000, function() {
    this.echo(this.getHTML());
});

casper.run();
```

after this I check the html code in 2.txt and I see it is giving me a resubmission error. How can I fix this?

Comment: someone please please help me i think it may be cookie isssues i am trying to automate checking my wifi minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a user agent, disable web security, and ignore SSL errors under `pageSettings`.

Edit:
  Code is not tested.

usage: `casperjs theFileName.js`

```
var casper = require('casper').create ({
  waitTimeout: 15000,
  stepTimeout: 15000,
  verbose: true,
  viewportSize: {
    width: 1280,
    height: 960
  },
  pageSettings: {
    "userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1262.0 Safari/537.10',
    "webSecurityEnabled": false,
    "ignoreSslErrors": true
  },
  onWaitTimeout: function() {
      // casper.capture('./out/wait-timeout:_' + TimeTidy() + '.png');
      // throw new Error stuff;
  },
  onStepTimeout: function() {
      // casper.capture('./out/step-timeout' + TimeTidy() + '.png');
      // throw new Error stuff;
  }
});

// Vars
var fs  = require('fs');
var url = 'https://www.bt.com/wifi/secure/statuscheck.do';

// Start
casper.start();

casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
  this.evaluate(function() {
    document.getElementById('username').value = 'yourUsername'; //+++ add your username
    document.getElementById('password').value = 'yourPassword'; //+++ add your password
    var loginButton = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox btn_login');
    loginButton[0].click();
  });
});

// Wait 2 sec then write to txt file
casper.then(function() {
  this.wait(2000, function() {
    var myData = this.getHTML();
    fs.write(myData.txt, myData, 'w');
  });
});

// Executes
casper.run();
```

Comment: thanks bro ive tried so many way to include my script with the above but i am struggling could you show me an example with my code encorperated

Comment: I updated my answer with a basic example.  Pay attention to the usage - you may or may not need sudo depending on your setup.  Do not use `test` in the usage.

Comment: Thanks for The Above this code did not fix resubmission but has added stuff i need i was told in another qeustion i asked it may be down to direct login i am new to casper so i dont know what this means but i would love this to work correctly i know when i log in on firefox it does make a redirect is there i way i can follow redirects

Comment: Change url to the homepage, then add code to the click the login button.  You should keep all questions related to your issue in one post, so that others can reference issues / examples.

Comment: okay sorry about that and could you have a look at the login page i am reqeusting as the homepage is that specific login page that i already using the url for

Comment: i think this may be the page i use as homepage i just dont know how to click buttons haha